# How to call a method using REST

Tags: rest

i have a rather general question: How to call a method in RESTful web service correctly?

The method is supposed to do only a transformation in the database and return nothing (so no GET?!). However I also send no values from the client (so no PUT/POST?!?).

So far I am using GET. Put i read thats not the proper way to do it...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you're looking for ping?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

REST stands for "REpresentational State Transfer".  If you're not transferring state representing the thing you're working with (in one direction or the other), it's pretty much inherently *not* RESTful, and there's no correct way of doing it and still calling it REST.

If you want RPC, then do RPC.  Just don't call it RESTful.  :)

Comment: Being REST and RPC, API architectural styles, would you consider acceptable (sure is technically possible) to mix it for an API definition as per the original poster example? Thx.

Comment: @GerardBosch: As long as you're willing to not call your API as a whole RESTful anymore, sure. :)  Of course you're free to *do* whatever works, and there's certainly value in RPC.  But RESTfulness by definition comes from restricting yourself in certain ways, and you don't get to say you have a REST API if it doesn't abide by those restrictions.

Comment: Thanks! I'm asking to learn and clarify best (or good) practices in API definition. From what I understand, they could co-exist for particular cases like @Todd Grigsby answer mentions.

Comment: Back to the OP, and considering e.g. an identifier sent as path-variable and that server triggers some action that mutates the state of the associated entity to the ID and could potentially return it (the mutated entity), Which verb should be used? (which one could make more sense?)

AFAIK and sticking to REST, PUT would be reserved on the case the client sends the whole entity to be replaced in the server. But in the case I present, the mutation process is a kind of side-effect completely unknown by the client.

Comment: @GerardBosch: We'd be a bit outside of REST at that point, i think, so it can't recommend us a verb. If i had to pick one, PATCH probably comes closest, with POST a distant second. PUT only really works if you're replacing the resource.

Comment: Maybe in terms of idempotence, PUT would still make some sense for an RPC-style operation. Wouldn't it?

Comment: @GerardBosch: Not really. Since semantically, PUT is for replacing a resource, the body should represent a replacement -- ie: the client would need to know what to replace it with. (If we're going to ignore semantics, we might as well just use GET. It has all the idempotence and none of the "what should the body be?" weirdness.) With PATCH, we could decide that all patches to a given resource mean "apply transform X", and if transform X is idempotent, then so is the request -- even if the client doesn't know it.

Answer (score 1):

The way you do it is through RPC.  REST is good for state transfer, but not for triggering actions that have nothing to do with state transfer, such as operations that affect a large number of records.  Most systems I've seen use REST for 99% of the work in supporting a UI, and RPC for that last 1% -- operations that do not involve state transfer, bulk update operations, that sort of thing.  Your goal should be to express as much of the business logic as possible as reaction to application of state, reserving the corner cases for RPC.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no "correct" way to do this if you're not transfering any kind of data. You're simply calling a method, so REST does not really apply.

Answer (score 0):

These days PATCH with a "JSON Patch" payload might be a way to go - but it's STILL not RESTful.

Calling it an RPC is more appropriate and no reason it cannot be in the same API as long as it is documented. Document your API with your RPC methods and REST resources separated.

E.g.

[image: RPC & REST example]

See:[Understanding RPC vs REST For HTTP APIs](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/09/understanding-rest-and-rpc-for-http-apis/)